# How can I run a python program in Komodo IDE like in IDLE(Python GUI) using Run Module feature?

Tags: python, path, python-idle, komodo, command-line-interface

Sorry I am a Python beginner and after several months with Python(GUI) I now want to move to Komodo IDE 8.5 (Suggested by posts on this forum), but I had trouble on configuring it to proper use. The main issue is how I can run a Python program in Komodo like in IDLE(Python GUI) using Run Module (pressing F5) feature?

When I pressed F5 in Komodo IDE 8.5, I got message "No Python interpreter is available".

I am using Python 3.30. Python.exe is in this path "D:\1_tools\python". Komodo.exe is in this path "D:\1_tools\komodo_IDE"

Thanks for any kind helpers. I have searched the forum but did not get any helpful info. Thanks again.

Comment: Do you have Komodo Edit or Komodo IDE? The integrated debugging is part of the IDE version only.

Comment: Hi Michael, it is Komodo IDE 8.5. Thanks.

Comment: Cool. What version of Python do you have and where is it installed? Is it on your PATH? Is it listed under Edit/Preferences/Languages/Python (or .../Python3)?

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks again! I am using Python 3.30. Python.exe is in this path "D:\1_tools\python". Komodo.exe is in this path "D:\1_tools\komodo_IDE". When I pressed F5 in Komodo IDE 8.5, I got message "No Python interpreter is available".

Comment: Is Python on your PATH? That is, if you open a command prompt and type `python` by itself, does it run? In Komodo, look under Edit/Preferences/Languages/Python3 and check the configuration. If python.exe is not on your PATH you can provide the full path to it there.

Comment: Thanks Michael!!!!! I have done it. I am very happy with this tiny step forward! :D

Comment: Yay! It's really great to be able to step through your code, look at variables, etc. Here's one of my favorite tips: I often write part of my program and step through that part in the debugger, and then write the next bit of code right there while the program is still paused. That way I can look at the actual variable values I'll need to use in the next part of the code.

Answer (score 1):

There is a thread on the Komodo Community Site that discusses this exact situation. (http://community.activestate.com/node/10113)

---

**Sumarizing:**

It seems that Komodo IDE defaults to using Python2 and since it can't find a Python2 interpreter, it complains.

**Solution**:

- For existing files, the suggested solution is to tell Komodo IDE (via "Properties and Settings" on the Editor Tab) that the file uses the Python 3 interpreter.
- If you create all new python source files using the Python3 template, the IDE will be able to run them. 
  **Beware:** The first time you want to use the Python3 template you will have to create the new file using the menu: "File" -> "New" -> "File from Template", then select the Python 3 template.

Answer (score 0):

> Is Python on your PATH? That is, if you open a command prompt and type python by itself, does it run? In Komodo, look under Edit/Preferences/Languages/Python3 and check the configuration. If python.exe is not on your PATH you can provide the full path to it there